# ComboBox will not bind to datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I bind a `ComboBox` to a datasource at design time.  The datasource is valid, I can preview the data in the `ComboBoxTasks` control.  Display and value members are set to columns in the datasource, yet, when the application runs.  I get no data.  Anyone had this problem before? I've also tried manually adding the items to the combobox properties at runtime to no avail.

```
//bind combobox
this.cboProperty.DataSource = usersDataSet1.Tables["properties"];
this.cboProperty.DisplayMember = "propcode";
this.cboProperty.ValueMember = "value";
```

Comment: Do you have a code or something?

Comment: Any code for us to look at?

Comment: When I do it in the designer, it's a hard link to the database, no?  Why can i see the data in a preview, but nothing shows up in the control at runtime?

Comment: Where's your `this.cboProperty.DataBind();`?

Comment: @mattmanser, this is WinFormApplication, not ASP.Net, as it is clear from the code... every thing seems to be right i dont know why spuy767 gets no data... First i asumed that table would have no rows, but he says that data is shown in ComboxBox Tasks

Comment: It works fine for me. Debug to check if the DataSet is populated properly before the binding. Also you can try to bind directly to a DataTable object which represents your "properties" table.

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are misnomers. The underlying object in the `Datasource` must have a property named with the string value, not just a member named with the string value.

So if your underlying object looks like this it won't bind

```
public class DataRow
{
    public string propcode;
    public string value;
}
```

But this will bind correctly.

```
public class DataRow
{
    public string propcode {get; set;};
    public string value {get; set;};
}
```

If you generated the dataset using the dataset designer, it will create the objects for you. If you create the dataset yourself in code, it does not do this for you.